how to use the \< command in the tabbing environment?
Excuse my ignorance, but how does the \< command (in tabbing) work? This document gets ! LaTeX Error: Undefined tab position.
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{1in}\=\hspace{1in}\=\kill
A \> B \\
\< left \\
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}

Lamport does not have an example of \< in his section on tabbing. The LaTeX Companion only talks about the error msgs raised by \<, saying (p.1546 of the pdf) "It can be used only at the beginning of a line (e.g., after \\)." Isn't that how the above uses it?
Putting it anywhere except after \\ raises the error given in the LC (\< in mid line), as far as I could tell.
I, or rather the search engines, could not find any example of using < anywhere. Thanks ...

It negates an earlier \+ (Kopka & Daly). If you don't have an earlier \+, you get an error.
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{1in}\=\hspace{1in}\=\hspace{1in}\=\kill
A \> B  \> C \\
\+\+ D \> E \\
\< left \\
\end{tabbing}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{1in}\=\hspace{1in}\=\hspace{1in}\=\kill
A \> B  \> C \\
\+\+ D \> E \\
\<\< left \\
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}



+1 it's a good job you answered before I did:-)

And this is decribed in Lamport too (in C.10.1)
